# Do Special MEA altitudes and routes in Alaska require WAAS?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules

Low Enroute IFR charts in Alaska (and maybe elsewhere?) have blue routes and MEAs for GPS equipped aircraft, such as T266, 7000G MEA, below. Is an IFR GPS sufficient to use these, or is WAAS required?

[image]

Comment: I thought WAAS was only required for precision (GPS) **approaches**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer appears to be yes. The [FAA document](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/notices/2013-11-14/AH03004.HTM) that describes this rule says:

> TSO C145a and TSO C146a GPS WAAS navigation systems are authorized to
>   be used as the only means of navigation on Federal airways and other
>   published ATS routes in lieu of ground-based navigation aids in Alaska

The [IFR chart legend](http://www.pra.org/publicdl/Ground%20School%20Training/NACO%20Aeronautical%20Chart%20Users%20Guides/8th_ifr_intro.pdf) says:

> To utilize these routes aircraft will need to be equipped with IFR
>   approved Global Navigation Satellite System (GNSS). In Alaska,
>   TSO-145a and 146a equipment is required.

And both TSO [C145](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgtso.nsf/0/8f5172f7537bbc6286256dad00643ce3!OpenDocument) and [C146](http://www.airweb.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgtso.nsf/0/BD9399D32EE5750A86256DAD00643D48?OpenDocument) specifically mention WAAS in their titles.

Comment: Live and learn :-)